# Most efficient way to check if $string starts with $needle in perl

Tags: performance, perl, string-matching

Given two string variables `$string` and `$needle` in `perl`, what's the most efficient way to check whether `$string` starts with `$needle`.

- `$string =~ /^\Q$needle\E/` is the closest match I could think of that does what is required but is the least efficient (by far) of the solutions I tried.
- `index($string, $needle) == 0` works and is relatively efficient for some values of `$string` and `$needle` but needlessly searches for the needle in other positions (if not found at the start).
- `substr($string, 0, length($needle)) eq $needle` should be quite simple and efficient, but in most of my few tests is not more efficient than the previous one.

Is there a canonical way to do that in `perl` which I wouldn't be aware of or any way to optimise any of the above solutions?

(in my particular use case, `$string` and `$needle` are going to be different in each run, so precompiling a regexp is not an option).

---

Example of how to measure the performance of a given solution (here from a POSIX `sh`):

```
string='somewhat not so longish string' needle='somew'
time perl -e '
  ($n,$string,$needle) = @ARGV;
  for ($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {

    index($string, $needle) == 0

  }' 10000000 "$string" "$needle"
```

With those values, `index()` performs better than `substr()+eq` with this system with perl 5.14.2, but with:

```
string="aaaaabaaaaabaaaaabaaaaabaaaaabaaaaab" needle="aaaaaa"
```

That's reversed.

Comment: Different versions of Perl are going to have an effect here and I recommend adding the benchmark code you used for feedback or reuse.

Comment: @Ashley, good point, updated.

Comment: Perhaps you will write `String::MoreUtils::XS` ?

Comment: Have you profiled your script to confirm that this micro optimization is actually needed?

Comment: FYI, you should use the [Benchmark module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) any time you want to benchmark something in Perl. `/usr/bin/time` will not necessarily give you a fair comparison.

Comment: If you're interested...I can post a solution in Raku. [ However, I humbly request that you first update the title of your question to include Raku, Ruby, etc. ].

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
rindex $string, $substring, 0
```

searches for `$substring` in `$string` *at position <=0* which is only possible if `$substring` is a prefix of `$string`. Example:

```
> rindex "abc", "a", 0
0
> rindex "abc", "b", 0
-1
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. It's the feature I wasn't aware of and was looking for. I get similar timings for both test cases in the question, and it's faster than any of the other approaches on both.

Answer (score 27):

How important is this, really?  I did a number of benchmarks, and the `index` method averaged 0.68 microseconds per iteration; the regex method 1.14μs; the `substr` method 0.16μs.  Even my worst-case scenarios (2250-char strings that were equal), `index` took 2.4μs, regex took 5.7μs, and `substr` took 0.5μs.

My advice is to write a library routine:

```
sub begins_with
{
    return substr($_[0], 0, length($_[1])) eq $_[1];
}
```

and focus your optimization efforts elsewhere.

UPDATE: Based on criticism of my "worst-case" scenario described above, I ran a new set of benchmarks with a 20,000-char randomly-generated string, comparing it against itself and against a string that differed only in the last byte.

For such long strings, the regex solution was by far the worst (a 20,000 character regex is hell): 105μs for the match success, 100μs for the match failure.

The `index` and `substr` solutions were still quite fast. `index` was 11.83μs / 11.86μs for success/failure, and `substr` was 4.09μs / 4.15μs.  Moving the code to a separate function added about 0.222±0.05μs.

Benchmark code available at: http://codepaste.net/2k1y8e

I do not know the characteristics of @Stephane's data, but my advice stands.

Comment: For the sake of argument, you may assume that that string matching is the critical point in my code and that all other possible optimisations have been done. In that regard, using a function will only decrease performance. But primarily, my hope when asking the question was that there was a better/canonical way to do that in perl.

Comment: For earlier `perl`s, you might want to [omit the return statement](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/06/perl-5-20-optimizes-return-at-the-end-of-a-subroutine/).

Comment: @ikegami `substr` seems to be the fastest when the prefix does not match because it limits the extent of the search.

Comment: NOT useless, @ikegami. Half of my benchmark cases were matches, half were match failures.

Comment: @SueD.Nymme: your posted answer is worded in a way that implies your worst-case test was only matching strings.  Clearly the worst-case for `index` is an extremely long haystack that doesn't contain the needle anywhere, so it has to check all the way to the end.  I'd agree with your conclusion, though: just use `substr`, since we've shown that it's not slower in common cases.  It should have a *much* better worst-case, which is important for resisting DOS attacks (or accidental slowdowns).

Comment: Instead of simply dismissing my benchmark results, you could try to reproduce them.

Comment: @SueD.Nymme: you're only testing with `length($needle) == length($haystack)`, which is weird.  You'd expect to see an even bigger difference between `substr` and `index` when `index` can spend time checking for matches at positions other than `0`.

Comment: @PeterCordes, and among the situations where the needle is not found in the string, there are those that are worse than others like the last example in the question where 111 byte-to-byte comparisons at least ((6+5+4+3+2+1)*5+6) are needed for a string of length 34 and needle of length 6. (it might even be the worst case scenario for string/needle this length, which would make for another interesting question here)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: some smart regex engines will avoid pitfalls like that by checking if the end of the string matches, to avoid going far into a matching prefix over and over.  `index` *could* do that, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. In `string="aaaaabaaaaabaaaaabaaaaabaaaaabaaaaab" needle="aaaaaa"`, how would checking the trailing `aaaaab` against `aaaaaa` first reduce the number of comparisons needed?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: oh you're right, in this case it won't help much if any, since there are more `a`s after every `b`.  So it's only one mismatching character, rather than a matching prefix with mismatches later.

Comment: "How important is this, really?" Enough for the OP to ask the question and for you to write benchmarks. That opening question serves no purpose other than to ding the OP for asking, and is in conflict with the rest of the answer. The advice to write a library routine is independent of the question, and actually supports the question, since library routines should strive to be efficient. The most efficient implementation is `rindex($_[0], $_[1], 0) == 0`, and this unusual usage of `rindex` can be hidden away in the library routine along with a comment explaining it.